# SELECT AND THEN UPDATE COUNT number mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all the rows from my table products, and then update the product_views too,
at the same time,

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = '26' AND `product_enable`= '1' AND UPDATE `product` SET `product_views` = product_views+1;
```

This code doesn't work, but i think can help for explain what i want to do,... Is there a good way to do this, I think with making this in 1 query should be good for the system right?

So, thanks for you help

Comment: You cannot use AND like this, AND is a WHERE clause.

Comment: It is possible to do in only 1 query??

Comment: do you want anything returned? if so no, if you actully don't, then yes see Loïc's answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just did it the wrong way :

```
UPDATE `product` SET `product_views` = 
     (SELECT product_views FROM `product` WHERE `id` = '26' AND `product_enable`= '1')+1;
```

Comment: This does not return any values which (if I'm reading the original post correctly) the OP wants.

Comment: i assumed she wanted rows returned, but if not, this is right

Comment: yes i want the rows returned, because i want to display the product fields, so i need to do in 2 queries right?

Comment: Yes then I think you need two queries. My bad, didn't understand the OP.

Comment: Though if you don't close / reopen the connection it's not a so bad thing to actually make two queries.

Comment: Ok, so i will make another query for update the count, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqli multi query: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = '26' AND `product_enable`= '1'; ";
$sql.= "UPDATE `product` SET `product_views` = product_views+1;";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

**Update 2:**

It is possible, check out: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Probably the error occurs because the last ; was missing (added it in).

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '26' AND product_enable= '1'; UPDATE product SET product_views = (SELECT product_views FROM product WHERE id = '26' AND product_enable= '1')+1;"`

Comment: plus you'd probably want to do the select afterward to get the new value of product_views.